# Looking for a quicker way to add alarms in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple elastic beanstalk environments. And I want to add multiple alarms to each of them.

One thing that annoys me is that I have to wait for about 1 or 2 minutes to complete adding a single alarm.

This means that I need about 1 hour to add all of the alarms to all the elastic beanstalk environments.

I don't want to spend so much time on adding the alarms.

Is there a way to batch add alarms to an elastic beanstalk environment?

The way I add an alarm is by clicking on the bell icon on the monitoring page in the elastic beanstalk environment.

[image]

Then set the details of the alarm -> click *Add* -> wait for about 1 to 2 minutes.

[image]

I've tried using terraform to update the environment. But there's a [bug in terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11056) that makes me difficult to determine if I have modified something unexpectedly in the environment.

One of the drawbacks of using [put-metric-alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) directly is that when I clone the EB environment, there won't be any alarms associated with the newly clone environment. I'll have to create alarms for the new environment manually.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier for batch operations to interface with AWS' API either via the CLI (if you like `bash`) or an SDK (if you like NodeJS, Python etc). If you were to use, eg, the Python SDK (`boto3`) you would use the [`put_metric_alarm()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_alarm) function

Comment: One of the drawbacks of using `put-metric-alarm` is that when I clone the EB environment, there won't be any alarms associated with the newly cloned environment.
I'm wondering if there are other solutions to avoid this problem.